# Doctoolchain Docker Container fails to pull in dependencies

Tags: asciidoctor, doctoolchain

I'm trying to get the doctoolchain running within our company, first goal is to publish to Confluence.

I'm using the docker image that includes pandoc as a base and add some certificates we need. This seems to work, I can connect to Confluence with

```
./dtcw docker image doctoolchain verifyConfluenceApiAccess -PconfluenceBearerToken=***  -PinputPath=src/main/asciidoc -PmainConfigFile=config/docToolchain.groovy
```

However, the trouble starts with publishing:

```
sudo ./dtcw docker image doctoolchain-core publishToConfluence -PconfluenceBearerToken=***  -PmavenRepository=https://nexus.company/nexus -PinputPath=src/main/asciidoc -PmainConfigFile=config/docToolchain.groovy
```

I get the following execption:>

```
* Where:
Build file '/home/dtcuser/docToolchain/build.gradle' line: 98

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'docToolchain'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration 'classpath'.
   > Could not find org.asciidoctor:asciidoctor-gradle-jvm:4.0.0-alpha.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://nexus.company/nexus/org/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-gradle-jvm/4.0.0-alpha.1/asciidoctor-gradle-jvm-4.0.0-alpha.1.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified
   > Could not find org.asciidoctor:asciidoctor-gradle-jvm-pdf:4.0.0-alpha.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://nexus.company/nexus/org/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-gradle-jvm-pdf/4.0.0-alpha.1/asciidoctor-gradle-jvm-pdf-4.0.0-alpha.1.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified
   > Could not find org.asciidoctor:asciidoctor-gradle-jvm-gems:4.0.0-alpha.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://nexus.company/nexus/org/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-gradle-jvm-gems/4.0.0-alpha.1/asciidoctor-gradle-jvm-gems-4.0.0-alpha.1.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified
   > Could not find org.asciidoctor:asciidoctor-gradle-jvm-slides:4.0.0-alpha.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://nexus.company/nexus/org/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-gradle-jvm-slides/4.0.0-alpha.1/asciidoctor-gradle-jvm-slides-4.0.0-alpha.1.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified
```

Running on non-company PC:

- just create an HTML page, but that requires the same libraries -> works
- create a small gradle build file that downloads one of the dependencies above -> 401 authentication error

Our Nexus usually serves as proxy for maven artifacts, but here it fails...no idea why, company IT says that some login is required for xillio artifactory, that would be consistent with the 401 on my PC

Answer (score 0):

thanx for the question.

We currently have two open Pull-Requests which should solve your problem:

https://github.com/docToolchain/docker-image/pull/60/
https://github.com/docToolchain/docToolchain/pull/1385

if you know the credentials of your nexus, you can specify them as

```
-PmavenUsername=User -PmavenPassword=Pass
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I looks like these  PRs do what I need :) We somehow survived so long with manual document creation, a few more days won't hurt :)